# Spark streaming - withWatermark() with duplicate behaviour

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I'm reading the data from Kafka (startingOffsets as earliest) and writing the data on console for few tests. Have given watermark duration of 10sec. Following the spark doc - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#streaming-deduplication

```
result_df = parsed_df\
    .withWatermark("event_time", "10 seconds")\
    .dropDuplicates(["uuid"])

result_df\
    .writeStream\
    .option("checkpointLocation", "gs://test/checkpoint_ts/")\
    .format("console")\
    .start()
```

**Passing below records one by one to kafka and reading each record from spark structured streaming:** ignore # onwards below

{"uuid":10150,"event_time":"2023-08-07T08:00:00.004071876Z"} # pass,displayed on console

{"uuid":10151,"event_time":"2023-08-07T09:00:00.004071876Z"} # pass,displayed on console

{"uuid":10152,"event_time":"2023-08-07T10:00:00.004071876Z"} # pass,displayed on console

{"uuid":10150,"event_time":"2023-08-07T11:00:00.004071876Z"} # discarded, not displayed on console (is this expected, given watermark threshold now is 2023-08-07T10:00:00 - 10 sec, so should not this record should pass through?)

{"uuid":10153,"event_time":"2023-08-07T06:00:00.004071876Z"} # discarded, expected given event_time is older than watermark threshold

**Question**: when reading the 4th record with uuid:10150, the watermark threshold is 2023-08-07T10:00:00 - 10 sec. Since first record with same uuid:10150 with different event_time falls older than current watermark threshold, should not 4th record pass through given spark streaming state store does not hold 1st record in memory for spark to detect this as duplicate based on uuid?

Answer (score 1):

The `dropDuplicates` operator is a bit subtle. Here are the two "modes" in which it works:

1. If you don't pass in an event-time column, it will keep state indefinitely. In this case, it does proper "global" deduplication, since it remembers everything it sees.
2. If you pass in an event-time column, it will clear state out that is less than the watermark. It also performs deduplication using all the columns that you provide.

### What you did

In your case, you only passed in a "value" column, i.e. non event-time column. This is "mode" 1:

```
result_df = parsed_df\
    .withWatermark("event_time", "10 seconds")\
    .dropDuplicates(["uuid"]) # <--- event_time not being passed in!
```

As a result, `dropDuplicates` will retain state indefinitely. Thus, records 0, 1, 2, and 4 in your example will be let through, but record 3 will be deduplicated because its UUID of `10150` was present in record 0.

### What you meant to do

Really, you meant to do the second "mode":

```
result_df = parsed_df\
    .withWatermark("event_time", "10 seconds")\
    .dropDuplicates(["uuid", "event_time"])
```

Let's consider your example assuming you did this. I am going to assume that each of these records get processed in its own batch, so that the watermark updates every record (Structured Streaming only updates the watermark per batch).

1. The first record gets processed. (10150, 8 hours) gets added to state. The watermark updates to 07:59:50. We emit the record, since it's unique.
2. The second record gets processed. (10151, 9 hours) gets added to state, the watermark updates to 08:59:50. We emit the record.
   Since the watermark is now greater than the event-time of (10150, 8 hours), the other record in state, we remove (10150, 8 hours) from state. Now, the only thing in state is (10151, 9 hours).
3. Same thing. (10152, 10 hours) is added to state, watermark updates to 09:59:50, we emit the record. Since the watermark is greater than the event-time of (10151, 9 hours), the other record in state, we remove (10151, 9 hours) from state. Now, the only thing in state is (10152, 10 hours).
4. Now, for some subtlety: this next record's uuid of 10150 is not globally unique, but since we dropped state due to the watermark, the operator doesn't know whether it has seen 10150 before. As a result, we *do* in fact emit this record. (10150, 11 hours) is added to state, the watermark updates to 10:59:50, and we remove (10152, 10 hours) from state.
5. At this point, the watermark is 10:59:50. Since this last record has a timestamp less than the watermark, we drop it, even though it's globally unique. In your `StreamingQueryProgress`, you would see that the `numRowsDroppedByWatermark` is 1.

### Why records get dropped

If you followed the example, you'll notice that we dropped records for *two* reasons.

1. The first reason is that we found a duplicate. This happens if a record we receive already exists in state.
2. The second reason is due to a *late* record. If we receive a record with event-time less than the watermark, we drop it (even if it's globally unique).

The second reason for dropping a record is not really related to deduplication. It just relates to the semantics of watermarks. A watermark gives us an event-time `t` before which we can expect to receive no more records. If the engine does receive a record with an event-time less than `t`, it will ignore it.

In Structured Streaming, this is the case for any in-built stateful operators, whether it's deduplication, aggregation, or stream-stream joins.

### In Conclusion

- If you have a `withWatermark` call on your stream, you should really be passing the name of the event-time column you're using to your `dropDuplicates` operator.
- Records with event-times less than the watermark get dropped.
- Records that are not globally unique, but are unique in-so-far as their duplicates have been already removed from the state store, will be emitted. This could lead to downstream duplicates, especially if your watermark delay is too small.
- If you *really* can't tolerate duplicates, set a big watermark delay or do true deduplication with no watermark.

Comment: This is a great answer. One question though... how is uuid 10153 dropped when it is unique globally?

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you for the updated explanation